# How can i redirect all denied domain name to another page in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

i use htaccess file to deny all requests to any page and allow only access from a list of some domain names. But i wish to redirect all denied domain names to another local page.

I wrote this in my htaccess file :

```
# intercept request
RewriteEngine On
<Files "mypage.php">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    #Allow from 197.149.16.181
    Allow from .*domain1\.com.*
    Allow from .*domain2\.com.*
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 ../you_are_not_authorised.html
```

But when a denied domain name or denied ip is opening the file, server still show its default 404 error page ><.

What have i omitted to do please?

Comment: The HTTP code for forbidden access is `403` not `404` (404 is "Not Found")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a custom page for denied requests you need to use `ErrorDocument 403` handler.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /you_are_not_authorised.html
```

It is advisable to give full path your custom error page that starts with `/`.

Comment: It solved my problem :D Thank you, but the trouble is the css style of you_are_not_authorised.php page seems not to be loaded, but only the file is shawn, is it normal?

Comment: That is due to your use of relative links for css/js etc.  You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.